# How to put 2 page numbering in Microsoft word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I'm helping my dad to make his book but I got this problem:

He wants the page to be in landscape format with two columns. And in each column, there are one page number each column. A picture below is the target outcome:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just a note, generally book formats are done by working in normal portrait modes, then printing them 2 to a page side by side. What he desires is easily done, by using the methods designed to "make that easy". Text flow , editing adding and subtracting things prior to  any printing then still flows to the pages, again making it easy.  A little training or tutorials prior to starting will help.  You really want to use the common method and programs intended design methods, fighting them is possible, just not long term.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [**Override page numbering in word**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/override-page-numbering-in-word/7895cf11-f2e9-4aa9-acfb-839d7b6f6358):

Where you have **Page 1 Here** you would need `{={ Page } * 2 -1 }` with the brackets inserted using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Where you have **Page 2 Here** You would need `{={ Page } * 2  }`.

This solution is **not** optimal. Like @Psycogeek's comment, I would suggest to use standard page numbering. Otherwise, you're going to have problem with the TOC, reference and so on...